# how do i convert a top level code written in playgrounds to iOS app

Tags: swift

I've tried coping the code from playground to iOS development environment it shows an error ="Expressions are not allowed at the top level"

I've copied this code from playgrounds to iOS viewController and AppDelegate

`var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(59, 28, 123, 50))
UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
ovalPath.fill()`

I've used this code to draw an ellipse.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that you might have put that code outside of any function codespace.

Make sure that the code you posted is within some sort of function like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    func someFunc() {
        // that code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That means the code is not contained in a function or a method.

So either put that code in a global function, or in a class/struct/enum method - most likely, considering what your code does, I presume it should be a method of a class inherited from `UIView` or similar